# Deserialize map of remote structs using serde_json

Tags: rust, serde, hyper

I have a use case that requires deserializing JSON into a map of "remote" (defined in another crate) structs. I've had a laughably difficult time with this, so I must be missing something obvious.

The following is essentially the desired end state:

```rs
use hyper::Uri;
use serde_json;
use std::collections::HashMap;

fn main() {
    let data = r#"
        {
            "/a": "http://example.com/86f7e437faa5a7fce15d1ddcb9eaeaea377667b8",
            "/b": "http://example.com/e9d71f5ee7c92d6dc9e92ffdad17b8bd49418f98",
            "/c": "http://example.com/84a516841ba77a5b4648de2cd0dfcb30ea46dbb4"
        }"#;

    let map: HashMap<String, Uri> = serde_json::from_str(data).unwrap();

    println!("{:?}", map);
}
```

which fails because:

```
the trait bound `Uri: serde::de::Deserialize<'_>` is not satisfied required because of the requirements
on the impl of `serde::de::Deserialize<'_>` for `HashMap<std::string::String, Uri>`
```

While the serde docs [describe a pretty nasty but potentially viable workaround](https://serde.rs/remote-derive.html) for deriving `Deserialize` on remote structs, it requires the use of `#[serde(with = "LocalStructRedefinition")]` on any referencing container type, which does not appear possible when creating a `HashMap`.

Intuitively this *must* be a common use case... is there a way to solve this that doesn't involve:

1. deserializing the data into a `HashMap<String, String>`
2. iterate through the map, parsing the values into a *new* `HashMap<String, Uri>`

Comment: Can you clarify *why* the two methods listed are unacceptable? You can create your own `struct MyUri(Uri)` and implement `Deserialize` on that to get a `HashMap<String, MyUri>`.

Comment: This is what I got, I am sure it can be improved to fit `2(no iter)` --> https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=476dfde77697d9a6338b613d3ccc0ab3

Comment: You could avoid the into and use MyUri as suggested by @kmdreko

Comment: Thanks for the help, both of you! 

@kmdreko it isn't necessarily unacceptable; it just feels suboptimal to load to load each value into memory twice (especially when the real-world JSON object contains hundreds of thousands of entries) and I figured there must be a smarter way to do this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With a mix of `Into`, `deserialize_with` and `flatten`, you can achieve what you want:

```
use serde_json;
use std::collections::HashMap;
use hyper::Uri;
use serde::{de::Error, Deserialize, Deserializer};

#[derive(Debug, Deserialize)]
struct MyUri(#[serde(deserialize_with = "from_uri")] Uri);

#[derive(Debug, Deserialize)]
struct MyUriMap {
    #[serde(flatten)]
    inner: HashMap<String, MyUri>
}

impl Into<HashMap<String, Uri>> for MyUriMap {
    fn into(self) -> HashMap<String, Uri> {
        self.inner.into_iter().map(|x| (x.0, x.1.0)).collect()
    }
}


fn from_uri<'de, D>(deserializer: D) -> Result<Uri, D::Error>
where
    D: Deserializer<'de>,
{
    let s: &str = Deserialize::deserialize(deserializer)?;
    s.parse().map_err(D::Error::custom)
}


fn main() {
    let data = r#"
        {
            "/a": "http://example.com/86f7e437faa5a7fce15d1ddcb9eaeaea377667b8",
            "/b": "http://example.com/e9d71f5ee7c92d6dc9e92ffdad17b8bd49418f98",
            "/c": "http://example.com/84a516841ba77a5b4648de2cd0dfcb30ea46dbb4"
        }"#;

    let map: MyUriMap = serde_json::from_str(data).unwrap();

    // let map: HashMap<String, Uri> = map.into();
    // I think to get HashMap<String, Uri> you have to do an iter as seen in the Into implementation
    println!("{:?}", map);
}
```

See in [Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=476dfde77697d9a6338b613d3ccc0ab3)

PS. In my answer, to get HashMap<String, Uri> you have to do an iter as seen in the `Into` implementation

Comment: Thanks for this! `MyUri` is definitely what I was missing. Just trying to learn here: is the `Into` implementation zero-copy (or gets optimized to zero-copy) such that the map is actually only stored in memory once?

Comment: I actually dont think you need to use into. This should just work right? https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=4cf620ba0fb7b9ed456578b8772c9089

Comment: I dont think its zero copy. And it seems its recommended to use `From` instead of `Into` https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/convert/trait.Into.html

Comment: This actually solves my real use-case, where I can use the `HashMap<String, MyUri>` and access the inner `Uri` on lookup – I figured I was looking at this problem the wrong way. I'm going to mark this as solved, but I think the other half of this is that there *isn't* a well defined way to implement zero-copy deserialization for a `HashMap<String, RemoteStruct>` with serde, if it were truly necessary.

Answer (score 1):

By using the [`serde_with`](https://github.com/jonasbb/serde_with) crate most of the deserialization logic can be reduced to an attribute.
It has the advantage of avoiding any wrapper types except for deserialization.

```rust
#[serde_with::serde_as]
#[derive(serde::Deserialize)]
struct Wrapper(
    #[serde_as(as = "HashMap<_, serde_with::DisplayFromStr>")]
    HashMap<String, hyper::Uri>
);

fn main() {
    let data = r#"
        {
            "/a": "http://example.com/86f7e437faa5a7fce15d1ddcb9eaeaea377667b8",
            "/b": "http://example.com/e9d71f5ee7c92d6dc9e92ffdad17b8bd49418f98",
            "/c": "http://example.com/84a516841ba77a5b4648de2cd0dfcb30ea46dbb4"
        }"#;

    let map: Wrapper = serde_json::from_str(data).unwrap();
    println!("{:?}", map.0);
}
```